# calling a function declared x.f = function() from other files -- js

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have a function declared

```
x.funstuff = function(){

}
```

When I want to call it within a file I simply declare

```
x = {};
```

However when I call it from another file I get issues. Even after I use x = {};

in that seperate file.

How does one call this function from another file?

Comment: What is the problem? What happens?

Comment: Okay nevermind. The issue seems more complicated. This is actually a dumbed down version of my code however I just tried running this code itself and it works. I am going to modify my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing it in the order specified then you are overwriting your `x` variable with a new object.

```
x.funstuff = function() {};

means that x = { funstuff: function() {} };

then x = {}; replaces it
```

If you are trying to call the function do it as:

```
x.funstuff();
```